# \fbox inside an imported pdf

Tags: boxes, pdfpages

I have imported a pdf using `\includepdf` and I want insert an `fbox` into the pdf (the pdf contains standard content that stays at the bottom).

I have used this code:

```
\includepdf[pages={1},pagecommand={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node at (1, 1) {
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \fbox{
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth - 2\fboxsep}
        text in box
      \end{minipage}
    } 
  };
\end{tikzpicture}}]{ficha.pdf}
```

It works but the `\fbox` frame is not visible. How can I obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

`\includepdf` sets locally the rule width `\fboxrule` and `\fboxsep` to zero, so you must reset them:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}

 \begin{document}
 \includepdf[
  pages={1},
  pagecommand={
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node at (1, 1) {
     \fboxrule=0.4pt \fboxsep=3pt
     \fbox{%
       \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth - 2\fboxsep}
         text in box
       \end{minipage}
        }
      };
\end{tikzpicture}}]{example-image-A}


 \end{document}
```

You can also use `\node[draw]` to draw a frame instead of the fbox.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the node's own boundary drawing and `\parbox` capabilities.

BTW, you should use `{\dimexpr \textwidth -2\fboxsep}`.  Then again, with `overlay` exceeding the boundaries is no big deal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[draw,text width=\textwidth] at (current page header area)
      {text in box};
\end{tikzpicture}}]{../blogs/kindle}
\end{document}
```

[image: cropped page]